# How to stop Unhandled Promise error when running node.js file in BigQuery?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running the following node.js code in BigQuery but I'm getting an unhandled promise error:

I'm not too familiar with node.js - do I have to add a .catch() in there at the end?

```
const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bigquery = new BigQuery({
  projectId: 'xxxxx',
  keyFilename: 'key.json'
});

const query = `SELECT total_amount, pickup_datetime, trip_distance
  FROM \`nyc-tlc.yellow.trips\`
  ORDER BY total_amount DESC
  LIMIT 1;`

bigquery.createQueryJob(query).then((data) => {
  const job = data[0];
  return job.getQueryResults({timeoutMs: 10000});
}).then((data) => {
  const rows = data[0];
  console.log(rows[0]);
});
```

Error:

```
(node:1035) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either
 by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not
 handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1035) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, p
romise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Thanks

Comment: `do I have to add a .catch() in there at the end?` why not try that first? This will also tell you why your code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I'm not familiar with .catch() or Javascript syntax so I'm not exactly sure what to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with @google-cloud/bigquery anyway you should do :

```
 .then((data) => {
  const rows = data[0];
  console.log(rows[0]);
}).catch(e=>{
//handle exception
console.log(e)
})
```